# Can one have matrix as vector elements in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

As the title says, I am using numpy and would like to have a (n,1) dimensional vector where each individual element is in fact a matrix.

I have found this answer: [Matrix of matrices in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856453/matrix-of-matrices-in-python/46859218#46859218) . Based on that post I tried writing the following code:

```
A,B,C = (np.full((3,3),k) for k in range(3))
D=np.block([[A],[B]])
print(D)
D[1]
```

However, this does not give me the array A, but instead gives me the first row of array A.

So, is there some way of doing this in numpy?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. I base this answer on the first line of your post. I don't think you can store numpy ndarray inside other numpy arrays. But, since it's 1D, a list does the trick. Simply create your matrix as np.ndarray and then add them to a list with the append method.

Comment: try this: ```D = np.array([A, B])```

Comment: @IrshadBhat That works. Thank you very much